# RegEx question: standardization of medical terms

Tags: regex, standardization

I need to detect words as 'bot/hersen/levermetastase' and transform them into 'botmetastase, hersenmetastase, levermetastase'.
But also 'lever/botmetastase' into 'levermetastase, botmetastase'.

So I need to be sure the "word/word/word metastase" is as variabele as possible in numbers.

This is my solution but it doesn't work.

**FILTERIN**:

```
\b(\w)\s*[\/]\s*(\w)\s*(metastase)\b
```

**FILTEROUT**:

```
$1metastase, $2metastase, $3metastase
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. But with regard to your regex: \w matches a single word character, not a word (this is \w+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/?(\w+)(?=(?:/\w+)+metastase\b)/?
```

Replace with `$1metastase`  (with space at the end).

If there can be spaces around the slashes, use

```
/?\s*(\w+)(?=(?:\s*/\s*\w+)+metastase\b)(?:\s*/)?
/?\h*(\w+)(?=(?:\h*/\h*\w+)+metastase\b)(?:\h*/)?
```

where `\h` matches a horizontal only whitespace char, and `\s` will match any whitespace char.

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/6tMxw7/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/6tMxw7/4).

**Details**

- `/?` - an optional `/` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(?=(?:/\w+)+metastase\b)` - that must be followed with

  - `(?:/\w+)+` - one or more occurrences of `/` and then 1+ word chars
  - `metastase\b` - and `metastase` whole word (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `/?` - an optional `/` char.

Comment: Thanks! If I test your answer with "hersen/bot/levermetastase" , I get "hersenmetastase, botmetastase, levermetastase, metastase" as a result but the last "metastase" doesn't belong there and is actually too much "metastase". Can you please help me again?